# Axios GET and jQuery getJson works different for same logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, vue.js, axios

I have a piece of code that uses the **jQuery** **getJson ()** method to get data about an file from API, this code works well for any size of the file sent to the API. And now I have to convert this **jQuery** code to **Axios**. The problem is that the **Axios** code works with a file size of less than 1.5 MB, for a larger file size, get **400** Bad Request. Both applications has the same headers and bodys. Where is my fault. If this could be useful, the **jQuery** code works with **RazorPage**, **Axios** with **VueJs**. Thank you in advance. Have a nice day.

```
  $.getJSON(apiURL).done(function(response) {/* Do something with response */ }).fail(function(error) { /* Do something with error */ })
  axios.get(apiURL).then(response =>{ /* Do something with response */  }).catch(()=>{/*Do something with error */ })
```

Comment: Can you give an API url that has file size more than 1.5 MB?

Comment: I mean, I'm sending a file through the post method to url , and with the get method I take this file with some modifications